# different behaviour of hoisting of functions

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {
   function myInternalFunction() {
      return 10;
   }
   return myInternalFunction();
   function myInternalFunction() {
      return 20;
   }
}
alert(myFunction()); // What will this alert?
```

**The answer is 20.**

```
function myFunction() {
   var myInternalFunction = function() {
      return "Hello World.";
   }
   return myInternalFunction();
   var myInternalFunction = function() {
      return "Second Definition.";
   }
}
alert(myFunction()); // What will this alert?
```

**The answer is "Hello Wold".**

Why???? why not "Second Definition" ????

Comment: See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/218196)

Comment: Why? Because in the first example you are using function **declarations** and in the second one you are using function **expressions**.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that's not equivalent to your previous example. You are calling `alert(a)` *after* the second assignment, so of course it alerts `two`. To make it equivalent to the function example, you would have to write `var a = 'one'; alert(a)', var a = 'two';`.

Comment: @FelixKling oh! thank you..... and now completely removed my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable’s *declaration* is hoisted, but not its *definition*. So your second example is equivalent to:

```
function myFunction() {
   var myInternalFunction
   myInternalFunction = function() {
     return "Hello World."
   }
   return myInternalFunction()

   myInternalFunction = function() {
     return "Second Definition."
   }
}
```

Here it becomes obvious that the `myInternalFunction` is unreachable, so the first definition is used as it is the value of `myInternalFunction` at the time it’s called. JSLint correctly complains (using your original code):

> Unreachable `var` after `return`.

---

Compare with your first example, where the *function declarations* are hoisted, so your code is equivalent to:

```
function myFunction() {
   function myInternalFunction() {
     return 10
   }
   function myInternalFunction() {
     return 20
   }
   return myInternalFunction()
}
```

As we can see here, `myInternalFunction` is immediately redeclared, and so the last one wins. Both declarations happen *before* calling the function itself.

---

> So, why this expressions alert lastly called variable:
>
> ```
> var a = "one";
> var a = "two";
> alert(a); // alerts two ???? shouldn't be "one" if expressions?
> ```

This isn’t equivalent to your function example; an equivalent example would be:

```
var a = "one"
alert(a)
var a = "two"
```

And expected it to alert “two”. I think it’s obvious it won’t. The value of the variable, be it function, string, or anything else, is not relevant.

Comment: what if, if I change last definition from function(){} to some string?

Answer (score 3):

Because, in the first case, during the compile time itself, second `myInternalFunction` replaces the first `myInternalFunction` in the current scope. It means that, only the second `myInternalFunction` function exists in the `myFunction`'s scope.

But in the second case, the functions are created during the execution only. By the time `alert` was executed, only the first `myInternalFunction` function was created, the second `myInternalFunction` is not created at all. That is why `Hello World` is alerted.

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand properly.

Comment: The second case uses variabel declaration. This means it will be created once that code is executed .. but you never execute that piece of code sense you have a return statement before that.

In the first case you simply state what functions existes in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Function declarations** and **variable declarations** are always moved (“hoisted”) invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter.

Note it has to be **Function declarations**, which means only the syntax of `function foo() {}` will be hoisted.

First code is equal to:

```
function myFunction() {
   function myInternalFunction() {
      return 10;
   }
   function myInternalFunction() {
      return 20;
   }
   return myInternalFunction();
}
```

Second code is equal to:

```
function myFunction() {
   var myInternalFunction;

   myInternalFunction = function() {
      return "Hello World.";
   }

   return myInternalFunction();

   myInternalFunction = function() {
      return "Second Definition.";
   }
}
```

Comment: according to your answer I've updated my question. please check that.

Comment: @C-link `var a = "one";
var a = "two";
` is just same as `var a; a = 'one'; a = 'two';`, so it's the result.